# Need UK transit visa?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, transit-visas

Respectfuly , please clearly answer to my question ,i don,t want after i buy the ticket i got the problem in airport ! 
My son come from Iran he has Shengen visa ,we want to go to Spain for 2 weeks , holiday , but the fly has 3 hours stop in London UK , i don,t know he need the transit visa or not because he has Shengen Visa ?! 
 please answer me as soon as possible !
 thanks  for your cooperation  with best regards  Shayesta

Comment: Kimyaee Having a Schengen ‘C’ visa is irrelevant, your son will need a visa to transit the UK. You don’t say what the departure point is but it will probably be easier to look for a direct flight to Spain, or one that transits in Schengen.